# Google Sheets not sum numbers correctly

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with many numbers generally in range 1.5-0.5 with lots of decimal places, however google sheets isn't doing sum on them correctly it returns 0.

I need all the decimal places so I can't round or anything.

[image: Sum not working properly]

Comment: Most likely it's the number format on that cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the data in columns B:E are formatted as text rather than numbers.

In Google Sheets you'd select those cells and choose `Format>Number>Number`.

See the example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B4W6DzsFAAI9nron8v_QXmaof_GrGB_TzTTp494RrUA/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Yes, try making the columns wider. If the contents align to the left of the cell, it is probably text.

Answer (score 0):

After importing a csv file with a column with different decimal values and applying Tom Woodward solution I got some crazy numbers. What worked for me was to select the columns and click first on `Format>Number>Plain Text` & second `Format>Number>Number` . Aparently some of the decimal values where considered dates after importing the csv file..(only when using Spanish as main language for the document...)